# How to update multiple columns of multiple rows in one SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, update

In my SQL Server database I want to update columns of multiple rows. I can do it for one row only:

```
UPDATE theTable
SET theColumn = case
WHEN id = 1 then 'a' 
WHEN id = 2 then 'b'
WHEN id = 3 then 'c'
WHERE id in (1, 2, 3)
```

How can I update more columns (theColumn2, theColumn3...) in the same query?

Answer (score 5):

You could supply the new values as a table (with the help of the [VALUES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql) row constructor), so that you could join it with the target table and use the join in the UPDATE statement, like this:

```
UPDATE
  tgt
SET
  Column1 = src.Column1,
  Column2 = src.Column2,
  Column3 = src.Column3,
  ...
FROM
  dbo.TargetTable AS tgt
  INNER JOIN
  (
    VALUES
    (1, 'a', 'k', 'x', ...),
    (2, 'b', 'l', 'y', ...),
    (3, 'c', 'm', 'z', ...)
  ) AS src (ID, Column1, Column2, Column3, ...)
    ON tgt.ID = src.ID
;
```

Answer (score 5):

An example of how this can be done (see SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0c320/5)):

(p.s. I used a [CTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression) (aka the `WITH` clause) and PostgreSQL (I don't use MS SQL Server) but the principles are very much the same - except for the `SERIAL` datatype - use MS's auto-incrementing type!).

Create and populate a source table (named one):

```
CREATE TABLE one
(
  record_id SERIAL,
  one_first_var INTEGER,
  one_second_var INTEGER,
  one_third_var INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO one (one_first_var, one_second_var, one_third_var) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO one (one_first_var, one_second_var, one_third_var) VALUES (2, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO one (one_first_var, one_second_var, one_third_var) VALUES (3, 3, 3);
```

And also a target table (two):

```
CREATE TABLE two
(
  record_id SERIAL,
  two_first_var INTEGER,
  two_second_var INTEGER,
  two_third_var INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO two (two_first_var, two_second_var, two_third_var) VALUES (21, 21, 21);
INSERT INTO two (two_first_var, two_second_var, two_third_var) VALUES (22, 22, 22);
INSERT INTO two (two_first_var, two_second_var, two_third_var) VALUES (23, 23, 23);
```

(double check your values in table two):

```
SELECT * FROM two;
```

And then run your update (multiple columns at a time):

```
WITH my_values AS
(
  SELECT 
         one_first_var, 
         one_second_var, 
         one_third_var
  FROM one
  WHERE one_first_var = 2
)
UPDATE two 
SET 
  two_first_var = my_values.one_first_var,
  two_second_var = my_values.one_second_var,
  two_third_var = my_values.one_third_var
FROM
  my_values
WHERE
  two_second_var = 22;
```

And then re-run your

```
SELECT * FROM two;
```

Again, see the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0c320/5)!

You can also use a `JOIN` to update the target record(s). I would encourage you to experiment with these techniques - very useful!

Your first result for two (i.e. inserted values) will look like this:

```
record_id   two_first_var   two_second_var  two_third_var
        1              21               21             21
        2              22               22             22
        3              23               23             23
```

and your second (updated) result will be:

```
record_id   two_first_var   two_second_var  two_third_var
        2               2                2              2
        1              21               21             21
        3              23               23             23
```